# How to get controller class in grails filter

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-filters

I need the class of the controllers that pass through a certain filter for annotation processing pruposes.

Currently I can only see the controllerName.

Is there anyway of getting the actual controller.class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) and you will see that you have access to the controller name in `controllerName` and many other values.

If you need the entire class name you can find it through:

```
grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", controllerName).clazz
```

Comment: There's an example of someone doing exactly that (accessing controller from filter) here: https://github.com/LanyonM/grails-feature-toggle/blob/master/grails-app/conf/grails/feature/toggle/filters/FeatureToggleFilters.groovy which is a fork from the (apparently unmaintained) feature-toggle plugin.